# How to bind visibility property

Tags: wpf, visibility, show-hide, adorner

The XAML code is as follows:

```
<Helper:BooleanVisibilityValueConverter x:Key="BoolToVisible" />
   <Control x:Name="ResizeDecorator" MouseMove="ResizeDecorator_MouseMove" Template=" {StaticResource ResizeDecoratorTemplate}" Visibility="{Binding IsButtonVisible,Converter= {StaticResource ResourceKey=BoolToVisible},RelativeSource={RelativeSource  TemplatedParent}}" />
<Helper:BooleanVisibilityValueConverter x:Key="BoolToVisible" />
<Control x:Name="ResizeDecorator"  MouseMove="ResizeDecorator_MouseMove" Template="{StaticResource ResizeDecoratorTemplate}" Visibility="{Binding IsButtonVisible,Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=BoolToVisible},RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"  />
```

The ViewModel code:

```
private bool _IsButtonVisible;
public bool IsButtonVisible
{
    get { return _IsButtonVisible; }
    set
    {
        _IsButtonVisible = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("IsButtonVisible");
    }
}

IsButtonVisible =false;
```

Can anyone tell me where am I going wrong?

Comment: Where is the xaml code ? Please post the question properly so that people can help you !

Comment: xaml
<Helper:BooleanVisibilityValueConverter x:Key="BoolToVisible" />

<Control x:Name="ResizeDecorator"  MouseMove="ResizeDecorator_MouseMove" 
                                     Template="{StaticResource ResizeDecoratorTemplate}" Visibility="{Binding IsButtonVisible,Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=BoolToVisible},RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"  />

Comment: You can add the code in the question by editing it. I will do it this time for you !

Comment: Please edit the question. The sentence "How to visible/hidden visibilty property in wpf" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Check in the Output window, you may get some hints. Can you show the converter code?

Comment: The Converter code is as follow:public class BooleanVisibilityValueConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                if (((bool)value) == true)
                    return Visibility.Visible;
                else
                    return Visibility.Collapsed;
            }

            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }

Comment: I'm guessing that the problem is that you are binding to IsButtonVisible on your templated parent.  Instead you need to bind to IsButtonVisible on the ViewModel/DataContext of your templated parent - i.e. Visibility="{Binding DataContext.IsButtonVisible,Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=BoolToVisible},RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}".

Comment: hi Jakob Christensen ....It works :) thank you very much

Comment: @jatinnahar: Great.  I copied my comment as an answer so that you can give it a vote if you like :)

Comment: yes sure...how to give vote...i m new to this site...please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that the problem is that you are binding to IsButtonVisible on your templated parent. Instead you need to bind to IsButtonVisible on the ViewModel/DataContext of your templated parent - i.e.

```
Visibility="{Binding DataContext.IsButtonVisible,Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=BoolToVisible},RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
```